CIFS mount from Windows fileshare is very slow, how to improve performance?
Setup
I have two different Ubuntu VMs (in different locations), that each mount a fileshare (so there are also two fileshares) located on dedicated Windows VMs using CIFS. I have roughly followed this guide to set it up. It looks like this:
myuser@myhost-cd-jd-1:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              794M  3.0M  791M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   48G   26G   20G  58% /
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  262M  1.6G  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-app          48G  200K   46G   1% /home
//10.232.32.100/lts                949G  645G  305G  68% /appdata/fileservice/mnt

The setup is generally working and I can access files from the mounted share in both locations. I have an application that basically lists all files from this shared location and uploads them somewhere else. However, I noticed the performance of just listing all files within a directory is vastly different on the two VMs.
Timings
On the fast VM, timing for counting all files looks like this (it's not exactly fast, but given there are ~700k files, it's OK)
$ time find . -type f | wc -l
683553

real    1m53.143s
user    0m0.514s
sys     0m1.789s

On the slow VM, even though there are significantly less files (<100k), the command runs for more than an hour now and I have eventually cancelled it. Going into some sub folder of the share returns the number of files after some time, but it's still intolerably slow.
Details on the file shares and structure
Both fileshares basically frequently get new data. Every couple of seconds, new image files are uploaded to the shares. I have read, that this is sub-optimal for the filesystem's indexing process.
The other major difference is folder structure. The fast VM/fileshare employs a date encoding in its directory structure, so the filesystem looks like this /appdata/fileservice/mnt/somefolder/24/06/30/01/image1.jpg - where each hour a new folder is generated and images are uploaded there. The slow VM/fileshare uses a filestructure like this /appdata/fileservice/mnt/somefolder/XXX_2024-06-25_03-38-40/image1.jpg (it creates a new directory every couple of seconds and puts one or two images in it)
Latency
Another difference between the two is latency. While in the fast example, Ubuntu VM and fileshare are colocated, in the second example they sit in geographically different locations. Still, I tested the latency using traceroute and it is in the range of 85ms (which I consider OK). For the fast example it is 2ms. As I'm so far only listing/counting files, I assume also bandwidth is not a limiting factor.
Questions
What can most likely be the reason for the big performance difference I get?
What can I do to narrow down/analyze the problem? I only have read access to the file shares.

traceroute means you are tracing an internet connection? If so there are hundreds of reasons 2 machines will give different results.

No, it's within a private network.

Just every Windows and Samba manuals says that it's better to share dirs from the root of the disk, because of the intrinsecally slow nature of share ACS's permissions. Try share from c:, not from some user folders...

(1) Post your cifs statements. (2) What version of Windows is on the server. If it's Win10 or Win11 there is absolutely no reason to use winbind for host name resolution or changing nsswitch when both Linux and Windows can use mDNS on a local lan.
